# tumblr API getting posts in php

Tags: tumblr

I am having difficulty using the tumblr-api to call posts from a blog. I am using the [api console](https://api.tumblr.com/console/calls/blog/posts) to get the code that gives me the variables for this, although i do not understand how to get those variables and output them to html.

```
    $client = new Tumblr\API\Client('PRIVATE KEY');

// Make the request
$client->getBlogPosts('tecksup.tumblr.com', array('type' => 'text', 'limit' => 6, 'filter' => 'text'));
```

this gets the variables as far as i know. 
Does anybody know how to call the variables(blogs, only two on this one) for an echo statement or at least to get the text to be formatted in the code after this? [This page](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts) has the documentation but I do not understand how to use what they are sharing.

Comment: loop the array as you require, does it deploys a json, an object, an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's usual for web API's to deliver the requested data as a JSON file.  Not so usual but possible is to deliver in XML, HTML TEXT, or a propietar format.

The process is the same, you have to decode the deliveredn data, assign to a variable, and loop the data as needed.

Tumbler response is a JSON formatted file.

Use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Comment: could you give an example, i do not know enough about php to figure it out so easily, sorry! although it seems what your saying should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this in the event that someone needs help getting the blog posts on an external site along with some styling. I am using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6 (yeah, alpha...I know). I'm also manually limiting the posts on the page by a simple counter. You could do the same with passing in the limit option on the api call(google it).

I am also using composer, Carbon, and the Tumblr API PHP. If you don't know what those are look at [packagist.org](http://packagist.org) to get started using composer and installing php packages. I am sure this thing can be refactored and maybe I'll edit my post once I get it done, but for now I think this may be useful to someone. Just edit this to suit.

Oh, this pulls in a Twitter feed as well. Just two columns next to each other.

```
<?php 
 require_once('../vendor/autoload.php');
 use Carbon\Carbon;
 $config_file = file_get_contents('../config/config.json');

 $config = json_decode($config_file, true);
 $key = $config['tumblr']['key'];
 $secret = $config['tumblr']['secret'];
 $oauth_token = $config['tumblr']['oauth_token'];
 $oauth_secret = $config['tumblr']['oauth_secret'];

 $client = new Tumblr\API\Client($key, $secret, $oauth_token, $oauth_secret);
 // This may break in the future if Tumblr issues a new oauth token set, it is at that point 
 // that one would create a token callback.
 // $client->setToken($token, $tokenSecret);  

 $info = $client->getUserInfo();

 foreach ($client->getUserInfo()->user->blogs as $blog) {
  // echo $blog->name . "\n";
 }
 $posts = $client->getBlogPosts($blog->name, $options = null);

 echo "<div class='row'>
         <div class='col-md-8'>";
$i = 0;
foreach($posts->posts as $post) {
$post_date = $post->date;
$date = Carbon::parse($post_date)->toFormattedDateString();

$body = $post->body;
if ($post->type == 'text') {
    echo "
      <div class='row mb-2'>
      <div class='card'>
        <div class='card-block'>
          <h4 class='card-title text-left'>{$post->title}</h4>
          <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-left'>{$date}</h6>
          <div class='card-text text-justify'>{$body}</div>
          <div class='card-text text-right'>
            <a href='{$post->post_url}' target='_blank'>
              <i class='fa fa-external-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>";
  } elseif ($post->type == 'photo') {
    $photo = ($post->photos[0]->alt_sizes[2]->url);
    echo "
      <div class='row mb-2'>
      <div class='card'>
        <div class=''>
          <img class='card-img-top rounded blog-img-top pt-4' src='{$photo}' alt='Card image cap'>
        </div>
        <div class='card-block'>
          <div class='card-text text-justify'>{$post->caption}</div>
            <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-left'>{$date}</h6>
          <div class='card-text text-right'>
            <a href='{$post->post_url}' target='_blank'>
              <i class='fa fa-external-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    ";
  } elseif ($post->type == 'quote') {
    echo "
      <div class='row mb-2'>
        <div class='card utility-padding-1' style='width: 100%;'>
        <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-left'>{$date}</h6>
        <blockquote class='blockquote'>
          <p class='mb-0 text-left'>\"{$post->text}\"</p>
          <div class='blockquote-footer text-left'>{$post->source}</cite></div>
        </blockquote>
        <div class='card-text text-right'>
            <a href='{$post->post_url}' target='_blank'>
              <i class='fa fa-external-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
          </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    ";
  } elseif ($post->type == 'link') {
      $link_photo = ($post->photos[0]->original_size->url);
      echo "
      <div class='row mb-2'>
      <div class='card utility-padding-1' style='width: 100%;'>
        <div class=''>
          <h4 class='card-text text-justify'>{$post->summary}</h4>
          <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-left'>{$date}</h6>
          <img class='card-img-top rounded blog-img-top pt-4' src='{$link_photo}' alt='Card image cap'>
        </div>
        <div class='card-block'>
        <div class='card-text text-justify'>{$post->reblog->comment}</div>
          <div class='card-text text-right'>
            <a href='{$post->url}' target='_blank'class='pr-2'>
              <i class='fa fa-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
            <a href='{$post->post_url}' target='_blank'>
              <i class='fa fa-external-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    ";
  } elseif ($post->type == 'video') {
     $video = $post->player[0]->embed_code;
      echo "
      <div class='row mb-2'>
      <div class='card'>
        <div class='embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3'>
          {$video}
       </div>
        <div class='card-block'>
          <div class='card-text text-justify'>{$post->caption}</div>
            <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-left'>{$date}</h6>
          <div class='card-text text-right'>
            <a href='{$post->post_url}' target='_blank'>
              <i class='fa fa-external-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>
    ";
  } else {
    echo "
      <div class='row mb-2'>
      <div class='card'>
        <div class='card-block'>
          <h4 class='card-title text-left'>Post type not recognized</h4>
          <h6 class='card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted text-left'>{$date}</h6>
          <div class='card-text text-justify'>Call your friendly neighborhood programmer</div>
          <div class='card-text text-right'>
            <a href='{$post->post_url}' target='_blank'>
              <i class='fa fa-external-link' aria-hidden='true'></i>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      </div>";
  }
  $i++;
  if($i==5) break;
}
 echo "</div>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <a class='twitter-timeline' href='https://twitter.com/[USERNAME]'>Tweets by [USERNAME]</a> <script async src='//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js' charset='utf-8'></script>
      </div>
    </div>";
?>
```